# How to print all lines from a CSV file that contains the exact match of a string from the nth column?

Tags: bash, awk, grep

I want to print all lines from a CSV file that match the character string `"ac"`. So if column 2 equals `"ac"`, then print this line.

Before

```
"id","make","model","yeear","product"
"11","ac","tot","1999","9iuh8b"
"12","acute","huu","1991","soyo"
"13","ac","auu","1992","shjoyo"
"14","bb","ayu","2222","jkqweh"
"15","bb","ac","8238","smiley"
```

After

```
"11","ac","tot","1999","9iuh8b"
"13","ac","auu","1992","shjoyo"
```

I attempted `cat file| grep "ac"`, but this will give me all lines that have `ac`:

```
"11","ac","tot","1999","9iuh8b"
"12","acute","huu","1991","soyo"
"13","ac","auu","1992","shjoyo"
"15","bb","ac","8238","smiley"
```

Comment: What is your question? I'm not quite sure what you try to achieve... Do you need to print all lines with the occurrence of *ac*?

Comment: @agentsmith I actually want to print all lines, in the second column, that only contain ac between the double-quotes. I'll update the post.

Comment: I assume the output given by ```grep``` is the expected result? Because that's exactly what grep is doing.

Comment: @CuriousSam Did you mean: ```cat file.txt | grep "ac"```?

Comment: @agentsmith Yes, I did. My apologies, long day.

Comment: @oguzismail ```awk -F, '$2=="ac"' file.txt > temp``` gives me an empty file.

Comment: @oguzismail I also tried ```awk -F, '$2 ~ "ac"' file.txt > temp``` but it that also included ```"12","acute","huu","1991","soyo"``` and that has the string ```acute``` in the second column

Comment: See also [useless use of `cat`](/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider surrounding double quotes:

```
$ awk -F, '$2=="\"ac\""' input.csv
"11","ac","tot","1999","9iuh8b"
"13","ac","auu","1992","shjoyo"
```

Or the same with regex pattern matching:

```
$ awk -F, '$2~/^"ac"$/' input.csv
"11","ac","tot","1999","9iuh8b"
"13","ac","auu","1992","shjoyo"
```

Comment: Hats off to you mate. Well appreciated.

Comment: Or if you want to eliminate the double-quotes `awk -F, '{gsub(/"/,"")} $2=="ac"' file`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Those double quotes are really handy but the info was great to know. I Appreciate it.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest What if I needed 2 columns to match exact strings like ac and 1992. Can you expand on your answer for me?